# Quasi-convex function must be "partially monotonic"?

Tags: optimization, constraint, convexity, convex-optimization

$f(x)$ is quasi-convex,

$$x^*\in\arg\min_{x\in C}f(x).$$

How to prove that, for any $a\in C$, $f(x) $ is weakly monotonic in the direction of $(x^*-a)$?

Is this simple result a part of an ancient theorem?

Comment: You can easily prove it, using the definition of function convexity and the fact that $x^*$ is a minimizer. I'm hesitant to say more, lest I ruin a perfectly good homework problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the definition of **quasiconvex**: $f(x)$ with compact support $C$ is quasiconvex if for two points in the domain $x_1,x_2$ and $w\in[0,1]$ $f(wx_1+(1-w)x_2)\geq \max\{f(x_1),f(x_2)\}$.

Let $x^* = \arg\min_{x\in C}f(x)$ where $C$ is the compact support of $f$. Then consider $x_1,x_2\in [x^*,\infty)$.

Choose $x_2>x_1$. By the definition of quasiconvexity, the secant segment from $(x_1,f(x_1))$ to $(x_2,f(x_2))$ lies below or at the maximum of the segment endpoints $\{f(x_1),f(x_2)\}$. Since $x^*$ is a global minimizer, we can choose $x_1=x^*$ which implies the right limit inequality:

$$\lim_{x_2\downarrow x_1} f(wx_1+(1-w)x_2)-f(x_1)\geq \max\{0,f(x_2)-f(x_1)\}~\forall w\in[0,1].$$ Thus the right derivative is non-negative. This then holds for all $x_1\geq x^*$. Thus $f$ is weakly monotone increasing on $[x^*,\infty)$.

We can do likewise for $x_1,x_2\in(-\infty,x^*]$ using left limits and show that $f$ is weakly monotone decreasing on $(-\infty,x^*]$.

Comment: Thank you kurtosis! I like your method but I am not sure if we are implicitly assuming that $f$ is differentiable (which is not necessarily true).

Comment: I suppose we could forego the limit existing (and hence the derivative) and just have the inequality be true ($\forall\delta>0:0<x_2-x_1\leq\delta\ldots$) and still get weak monotonicity.